# Check File Existence with Makefile Conditional

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to check the existence of a file using Makefile conditionals.

I've tried the following syntax which don't seem to work:

```
Path = /usr/local/myFileVer1
ifeq ($(wildcard $(Path)),)  
version = 1
else
version = 2
endif
```

I thought the wildcard statement would evaluate to an empty string if the file did not exist so it would fall into the else statement.  That isn't happening.

Any idea what else I can try?

Answer (score 5):

You're close to the syntax. You can try something like this:

```
File = /usr/local/myFileVer1

ifeq ($(wildcard $(File)),)
all:
    echo 1
else
all:
    echo 2
endif
```

Or better, you can write two separate makefiles and include them at the right places:

```
File = /usr/local/myFileVer1

ifeq ($(wildcard $(File)),)
include Makefile1.mk
else
include Makefile2.mk
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Make, like all UNIX utilities, is case-sensitive.  `PATH` is not the same as `Path`.

Also, you should not set the variable `PATH` as this will change the `PATH` when commands are invoked, and then your recipes will all fail.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped.  I will edit the question to show I don't use PATH.

Comment: You're missing an open parenthesis after the `ifeq`.  Is that also a typo?  In general it's best if you reproduce the error, then _cut and paste_ the exact makefile into your question so you don't have to worry about typos.  Even a single character completely changes the meaning, in programming.  Also, you say it "isn't happening"; how do you know the wrong part of the if statement is being chosen?  Maybe the problem is there, not in the if statement.